# Err 1004 "Cannot get pivotfield from pivottable"

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Altough the topic is out there, in terms of error 1004 in pivotfields, I just haven't seen this situation, that I need to resolve, and don't have any clue as to how.

This is a recorded macro code:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SybusPivotTable").PivotFields("Lote")
    .PivotItems("0").visible = False
    .PivotItems("ERRO").visible = False
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SybusPivotTable").PivotFields("Referência")
    .PivotItems("").visible = False
    .PivotItems("0").visible = False
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SybusPivotTable").PivotFields("tipo_mov")
    .PivotItems("2").visible = False
End With
```

I recorded it, and when a run the macro...
err 1004.

It's a recorded code, so I expected it to run like a charm. But no. The err shows up in the first line of code.

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the `ActiveSheet` is not the one with the pivot table if you run the macro?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you to find the guilty party of the error (I commented after each row to explain what the error means).

Give it a try :

```
Sub test_JDF()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, _
    Pt As PivotTable, _
    Pf As PivotField

Set Ws = ActiveSheet
'Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet_Name_To_Be_Replaced")
Set Pt = Ws.PivotTables(1) 'if error pops here, there is no pivottable on the active sheet
Set Pt = Ws.PivotTables("SybusPivotTable") 'if error pops here, there is no pivottable on the active sheet that is named "SybusPivotTable"
Set Pf = Pt.PivotFields(1) 'if error pops here, the pivottable is empty of pivotfields (highly unlikely)

Set Pf = Pt.PivotFields("Lote") 'if error pops here, there is no pivotfield name "Lote" in the pivottable
With Pf
    .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("ERRO").Visible = False
End With

Set Pf = Pt.PivotFields("Referência")
With Pf
    .PivotItems("").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
End With


With Pt.PivotFields("tipo_mov")
    .PivotItems("2").Visible = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the help. Although I understand your approach, I can manually verify that the sheet, pivottable and pivotfield all exist. I'm looking at the sheet when running the code. The difficulty, I believe, is if Excel is not recognizing one of these objects for any reason. Your code does solve the debugging part, no doubt. I searched the net for some anwsers, but the problems seem like witchcraft or something. But thanks anyway. I'll do it this way to try and find the problem.